# Serilog not printing Trace.WriteLine

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

We spotted a little issue with Serilog for c# - it's not printing anything that comes from Trace.WriteLine, even if the minimum log level is set to Verbose.

Project setup:
.NET Core 2.2, Serilog.AspNetCore 3.2.0

Any ideas?

Comment: File permissions are correct?

Comment: Ok, but could you be more specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I found the solution. You need to add TraceListener https://github.com/serilog-trace-listener/SerilogTraceListener.